# Please explain Portia's soliloquy from "The Merchant of Venice"

Tags: shakespeare

> The quality of mercy is not strain'd,
>   It droppeth as the gentle rain from heaven
>   Upon the place beneath. It is twice blest:
>   It blesseth him that gives and him that takes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary analysis.

Comment: The Bard is taking up time while the other actors are getting ready for another scene...

Answer (score 1):

It means that showing mercy is beneficial to both the person showing mercy and the person they're showing mercy to.